# Is it possible to search for Twitter account's retweets of another twitter account?

Tags: twitter, retweet

I know there is a function to search a person's retweets but is there a step further where you can search for another party included in the retweet?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is! However, it is a bit tricky and unstable. You'll have to do the following:

1. Create a Twitter list and add to it the `[retweeting_account]`. Just this one!
2. Construct the following search query: `filter:nativeretweets list:[your_list_id] @[retweeted_acount]`

So, for example, if you wish to see all the retweets @realDonaldTrump did for his wife Melania, the query should look like this:

```
filter:nativeretweets list:1336103232754618374 @FLOTUS
```

The only problem [with this](https://twitter.com/search?q=filter%3Anativeretweets%20list%3A1336103232754618374%20%40FLOTUS&src=typed_query&f=live) is that it seem to give results a week back, not more + it is somewhat unstable when used on really high traffic accounts.

In some cases the below variations seem to work while the above one doesn't:

```
filter:nativeretweets list:[your_list_id] link:[retweeted_acount]
```

or

```
filter:nativeretweets list:[your_list_id] from:[retweeted_acount]
```